# How do I register a Web Reference for a SQL Server 2008 Reporting Service Report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to access the Reporting Services via Web Services in my Visual Studio 2008 Application.  How/where can I find my WSDL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The following example shows the format of the URL to the Reporting Services management WSDL file:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx)

http://server/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169816.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that although Gulzar has indeed posted the correct answer, it only works if you have your Web Service URL set to the default - if not then it won't work.

Make sure you check which URL is correct - in Reporting Services Configuration Manager go to the Web Service URL section and see what's in the "Report Server Web Service URLs" box.
This may also include the Port number, though if it's Port 80 you can leave this out.

Also, for some reason even though this is Sql Server 2008 & Reporting Services 2008, the asmx is ***still*** ReportService2005.asmx. For some reason this hasn't been updated.

So the URL should be:

http://MyReportServer:PortNumber/WhateverUrlTheWebServiceIsSetAs/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl

Hope this helps!